# " Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances"

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, physics

I know that there are similar questions on stack exchange. However, I am relatively new to mathematica, so I couldn't really understand the answers. Sorry.

Here's my code:

```
k = 50000000;
c = 37;
g = 9.81;
\[Mu] = 0.3;
i = 10^-5;
l = 0.1;
m = 0.35;
NDSolve[
 {m y''[t] == -k z[t]^(3/2) - c z'[t] - m g,
  \[CurlyPhi]''[
    t] == ((-k z[t]^(3/2) - c z'[t]) l Sin[\[CurlyPhi][
         t]] + \[Mu] (-k z[t]^(3/2) - c z'[t]) Cos[\[CurlyPhi][t]])/i,
  z[t] == y[t] - l Cos[\[CurlyPhi][t]],
  
  
  y[0] == 0, y'[0] == -3, \[CurlyPhi][0] == 0, \[CurlyPhi]'[0] == 0, 
  z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0}, {y[t], z[t], \[CurlyPhi][t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

The error message is `NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.`

Is there any way to solve the equations numerically and plot graphs of them as a function of time. Thanks

Comment: With these parameters and initial data solution is complex, and therefore with algebraic solver we can't solve this system. It is why you got the message.  Do you try to solve collision problem with using the Hertz model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z[t] == y[t] - l Cos[\[CurlyPhi][t]]` is an algebraic equation, Delete it and define instead: `z[t_] = y[t] - l Cos[\[CurlyPhi][t]]` and delete the initial conditions for z:

```
k = 50000000;
c = 37;
g = 9.81;
\[Mu] = 0.3;
i = 10^-5;
l = 0.1;
m = 0.35;
NDSolve[
 {m y''[t] == -k z[t]^(3/2) - c z'[t] - m g,
  \[CurlyPhi]''[
    t] == ((-k z[t]^(3/2) - c z'[t]) l Sin[\[CurlyPhi][
         t]] + \[Mu] (-k z[t]^(3/2) - c z'[t]) Cos[\[CurlyPhi][t]])/i,
  z[t] == y[t] - l Cos[\[CurlyPhi][t]],
  
  
  y[0] == 0, y'[0] == -3, \[CurlyPhi][0] == 0, \[CurlyPhi]'[0] == 0, 
  z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0}, {y[t], z[t], \[CurlyPhi][t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Hi, nothing is showing up on the graphs when I use `Plot[y[t] /. a, {t, 0, 0.1}]
Plot[z[t] /. a, {t, 0, 0.1}]
Plot[\[CurlyPhi][t] /. a, {t, 0, 0.1}]`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Issok just figured it out. Looks like I have to take the real part of the solution